# WTForm: Update user information without adding the blank fields?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am trying to add a update profile information section to my website. And whenever I do update the information it deletes the previous information when the field is left blank, and replaces it with a None value. Which is obviously not what I want when people update their profiles.

This is my form:

```
class EditForm(Form):
    displayname = StringField('displayname', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=3, max=25)], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    status = StringField('status', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=1, max=64)], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    gender = StringField('gender', validators=[Optional(),Length(min=3, max=25)], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    age = IntegerField('age', validators=[Optional(),NumberRange(min=1, max=2)], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    pref = TextAreaField('pref', validators = [Optional()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    about = TextAreaField('pref', validators = [Optional()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    img =StringField('Image Url', validators = [Optional(), Length(max = 100)], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
```

As you can see, I have optional added and filters.

For the page itself, I have the following:

```
@app.route("/settings" , methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def settings():
    user=g.user
    error=None
    userInfo = UserSettings.query.filter_by(username=user.username).first()
    formo = EditForm(request.form)
    if formo.validate_on_submit():
        userInfo.displayname = formo.displayname.data
        userInfo.status=formo.status.data
        userInfo.gender=formo.gender.data
        userInfo.age=formo.age.data
        userInfo.pref=formo.pref.data
        userInfo.about=formo.about.data
        userInfo.img=formo.img.data
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('dash'))
    return render_template("settings.html", error=error, formo=formo, userInfo=userInfo, user=user)
```

Is there a different way to go about this?

Comment: You should look at using `formo = EditForm(obj=userInfo)` to pre-populate your form. You can also use `formo.populate_obj(userInfo)` to simplify your update.

Comment: This actually works really well with what I need for my site. Thank you very much!

Comment: @dirn why don't you add it as an answer.